# Are the muscles of all animals mechanically similar?

Tags: zoology, muscles, bio-mechanics

For instance, is the [skeletal muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle) of an elephant made of the same balance of fibers and cells as the skeletal muscle of a hippopotamus?

I recognize that [slow- and fast-twitch muscles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle#Twitch_speed) are a thing, and that [which animals have which vary](https://www.nature.com/articles/335824a0). I also recognize that different animals might have different numbers of mitochondria per muscle cell, and that there's a difference between skeletal, [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_muscle), and [cardiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_muscle) muscle, but am still conflicted on one thing **would it be accurate to claim that the mechanical properties, density, and the like of all types of animal skeletal muscle are the same?**

If you happen to have a source for your answer, please supply one - it'll be useful for something I'm trying to write.

Comment: I recall Comparative Biomechanics by Vogel stating the power density is roughly similar. Similar enough to group together and make comparisons with groups of man made actuators.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be answerable by anything other than opinion — can you please specify your criteria for "similar".

Comment: @tyersome Having similar physical densities, compressive and tensile strengths, Young's moduli, extensibilities, and so on and so forth - essentially, properties of the muscle in regards to materials science.